# Slider pagination using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I'm trying to create a slider where it has a pagination.  
Just for example in this jsfiddle I made 
http://jsfiddle.net/ALtW9/

This is what I have tried so far

```
$('#a1').click(function () {
   $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: 0
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
});


$('#a2').click(function () {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
});
```

There is a 1, 2 ,3 at the top that indicates a number. 
When I click the 3, it will animate to move to the 3rd div. When I click the first it will move to the first one so on and so forth. 
The current script only moves to next and previous. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using NivoSlider. You can replace the pagination with numbers in the settings

[Nivo slider](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider)

Comment: Sorry, I want to learn how to do it, not just by relying on plugins thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using bxslider (http://bxslider.com). It is extremely customisable and will allow you to do the above.

Comment: Sorry, I want to learn how to do it, not just by relying on plugins thanks :)